# max - min of an LP

Tags: linear-programming, polyhedra

I am reading a proof which states without proof that:

If a polyhedron $P$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ has dimension dim($P$) $\geq 1$ then there exists $c\in\mathbb{R}^n$ such that max$\{c^Tx\text{ }|\text{ }x\in P\} - \text{min}\{c^Tx\text{ }|\text{ }x\in P\} = 1$.

Apparently this is supposed to be straightforward, since no proof is given, but I do not know why this is true. Would someone be able to help clear this up for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can get $\max(c^Tx) - \min(c^Tx) > 0$ for some $c$, then scaling $c$ suitably gives what you want.

Comment: Great, thanks. I guess it is trivial to find $c$ so that max$(c^Tx) > $ min$(c^Tx)$ (as opposed to max$(c^Tx) = $ min$(c^Tx)$) since the dimension of the polyhedron is non-zero.

Comment: Yes, unless I'm mistaken we don't even really need anything about polyhedra *per se* for that, just the fact that there are two different points in $P$.

Comment: Oh, yes, good point! The context for me is with a polyhedron, but as long as there are distinct points $x$ and $y$, they will disagree on some coordinate at some index $i$, so then the preliminary choice of $c$ can just be taken as 1 for the special index $i$ and 0 elsewhere. Then possibly scaling $c$ provides the 'real' $c$ which satisfies the assertion. Thanks!